# How to get colors from color.xml in values-night folder even in light theme?

Tags: android, colors, styles, android-theme, android-styles

I have one page where I need to use colors from night mode regardless of current app/phone theme.

Let's say I have `colorAppBg` declared in both `values/colors.xml` and `values-night/colors.xml` with different hex.

How can I get `colorAppBg` from `values-night` folder for 1 specific fragment?